# Python Threads with Classes

Tags: python, multithreading

I was going to post an example, but i said screw it and am just posting what i have instead. Go easy on me. I'm used to ruby. Python is brand new to me.

I have a file called que that holds a bunch of songs. i want to make a background thread that constantly checks to see if que has any songs in it. If it has songs in it then play the song on the first line, then remove the first line. (.que.swp).

Now the problem is, i don't know how to do this all in the background. I have another class that allows the user to add songs to the que file. So they need to be running at the same time.

```
class MusicPlayer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MusicPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.que_file = "que"
        self.playQue()

    def playQue(self):

        while 1:
            try:
                f = open(self.que_file, "r")
                songUp = f.readline()
                songUp = songUp.rstrip()
                cmd = "cvlc \"%s\" vlc://quit &>/dev/null" % (songUp)
                os.system(cmd)
                data="".join(open(self.que_file).readlines()[1:-1])
                open(".que.swp","wb").write(data)
                os.remove(self.que_file)
                os.rename(".que.swp", self.que_file)
                print "\n%s added %s to the que" % (self.user, self.dir)
            except:
                print "No Que File Exists"
                time.sleep(1)

#main#          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = MusicPlayer()
    player.start()
    print "helloWorld"
```

"helloworld" never prints to the terminal. it just keeps looping my class. 
ps - if it makes you feel better you can clean up any of my ugly commands. Remember I'm new. I've been at this a few hours and have resorted to asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The looping starts not at the `player.start()` line as you might be guessing, but at the line:

```
player = MusicPlayer()
```

This is because you call `self.playQue()` in `__init__`. If you remove that line, and change the name of the method `playQue` to `run`, the thread should run separately.

See the [instructions for the threading package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) for a description of `start` and `run`:

> start()
>
> Start the thread’s activity.
>
> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the
>   object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

Comment: Thanks you! That was driving me crazy. I actually didn't know that's what the run method was for. Definietly noted for the future